# Error while flattening a list using pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I was trying to come up with a function on my own that would flatten a list of lists. Below is my code

```
flatten :: [[t]] -> [t]
flatten [] = []
flatten x:xs = x ++ (flatten xs)
```

When I try to compile the code above (contained in a file test.hs), I get the following error:

```
tests.hs:3:1: Parse error in pattern: flatten
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add parens around the `x:xs` pattern, so `flatten (x:xs) = x ++ (flatten xs)`

Comment: @Alec It worked, thanks. But how did parens make a difference?

Comment: I got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311918/parentheses-in-the-pattern-matching-in-a-function-declaration-haskell